# How to install pytorch=1.0 and why pytorch installing command no longer work

Tags: installation, pytorch, abi

In https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/, the way to install pytorch 1.0 is to run "conda install pytorch==1.0.0 torchvision==0.2.1 cuda100 -c pytorch". It failed because pytorch==1.0.0 can no longer be found. How should I fix that?
My python version is 3.6.

BTW, does anyone have a wheel for pytorch=1.0 with '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0'? I ran "conda install pytorch==1.0.1 -c pytorch" successfully but the torch._C._GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI param is True. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: An update to Python 3.12.1 will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should download wheel file directly. And use `pip install xxx.whl`.

I build a web tool, you can find and download specific version of pytorch.

https://install.pytorch.site/?device=CUDA+10.0